# How to show all users in "Select People and Groups" dialog box?

Tags: permissions, people-picker

Is there a way to show "All Users/Groups" in the Select People and Groups dialog?

[image: Select People and Groups]

I have tried "*" and "%" but they come back with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't any OOB method to show **ALL USERS**, however if you bind it to a SharePoint Group... then all users in the group will be displayed by default...

But limiting it to a group will allow to select people from the Group only!

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks - helps in that I know what it can't do!  It's actually on the Admin side, rather than user side I was thinking.  I work in the Middle East, and spellings and pronunciations and ways names are written often don't match...so being able to scroll through all users would have been very useful!